# Docker freeze while running with pycharm

Tags: docker, docker-compose, pycharm

I work on Ubuntu and I used this tutorial to configure my project with docker:

```
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-docker-compose-as-a-remote-interpreter.html

While staring my docker container with pycharm it logs that:

/usr/bin/docker-compose -f /home/przemysaw/Documents/proj_namev/docker-compose.yml -f /home/przemysaw/.PyCharm2019.1/system/tmp/docker-compose.override.54.yml up --exit-code-from api --abort-on-container-exit api

proj_name-cache-develop is up-to-date
proj_namev-db-develop is up-to-date
Starting proj_namev-api ... 
Starting proj_namev-api
Attaching to proj_namev-api
```

And this is it It it Attaching to proj_namev-api forever... It looks as if it was frozen.

Comment: Looks like? Or is frozen/hanged? It should show logs from your container after attaching.

Comment: what does it have to do with pycharm? does it work when you run it in the terminal?

Comment: @Efrat It work fine from the terminall. But I can't use it from terminal what is useful

Comment: can your see your containers when you `docker container ls` them? whats their status? can you `ping` them?

Comment: @efrat So invoking `docker container ls` is the same when I run it from comand line(`docker compose up`) and pycharm. The difference is that when I run it from pycharm there are no logs(docker logs proj_namev-api). The logs appears only when I start my docker from command line. What is more I can't access it even though the `docker container ls` says that it is up and ported  0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp. Well... This is very strange